# Strange spacing when putting a math macro before a binary operation

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators

I found there to be very odd spacing when using a math macro just before a binary operation. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\begin{document}

$x\otimes \id$

$\id \otimes x$

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I am aware that sometimes a macro "eats up" the space after it, requiring that we put it in braces or put a `\` after it, but I wouldn't have expected the space **after** the operation to be what is affected. Can someone explain what is going on, and how I could set this up differently so that the spacing will turn out correctly?

Comment: One should write `\newcommand{\id}{\mathop{\mathrm{id}}\mathopen{}\mathord{}}`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16699

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those are TeX's rules. You're defining `\id` as an **Op** atom (math operator), whereas `\otimes` is a **Bin** (binary operation) and `x` is an **Ord** (ordinary symbol). Thus `$\id\otimes x$` would be interpreted as

> **Op Bin Ord**

but this is not accepted by the rules, so the **Bin** atom is changed into a **Ord** (think to `$\sin -x$`, which is not what is usually printed, but would be surely wrong if it was "sine minus x").

Therefore the final sequence of math atoms is

> **Op Ord Ord**

and the spaces inserted are

> **Op** (thin space) **Ord** (no space) **Ord**

If your `\id` macro is for denoting the identity map, it shouldn't be a math operator, but an ordinary symbol:

```
\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}
```

In this way `$\id\otimes x$` would be

> **Ord** (medium space) **Bin** (medium space) **Ord**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful. But, I'm still unclear on why `\id` shouldn't be considered similarly to `\sin` - they are both special functions we want to give unitalicized names to, and I'm not sure what I'd do with one that I wouldn't do with the other. Could you explain (or link to an explanation of) the different ways of putting upright text in math mode, and when we should use each?

Comment: Since you won't be writing `$\id x=x$` but rather `$\id(x)=x$`, there's no point in defining it as a math operator. Function symbols such as `\sin` and `\log` are frequently used in combinations like `\log\sin x` where a thin space is needed, while your identity probably isn't used like this.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I've always preferred putting parentheses even for things like `\sin` and `\log`, to avoid ambiguity, which is probably why I never noticed.

Answer (score 6):

For correct spacing around `\otimes` - a binary operator, I would make sure that the operator `\id` resembles an ordinal symbol by wrapping it inside a group `{}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\begin{document}

$x \otimes {\id}$

${\id} \otimes x$

\end{document}
```