# Distance to semicolon in math mode

Tags: math-mode, typography

When using colon (`:`) in math mode, it always appears equidistant from the objects on either side of it.

Observe this *e.g.* when typesetting `$(a:b)$`.

If one instead uses `$(a \colon b)$`, the colon is closer to the *a*, as it would be in ordinary writing.

On the other hand, if one typesets `$(a;b)$`, one finds that the semicolon is not equidistant between *a* and *b*, but closer to the *a*, as with the `\colon` command above.

So my question is: Is there a command that creates a semicolon equidistant from the objects to either side of it, as with the `:`?

Comment: Use `$(a \mathbin{;} b)$`...

Comment: See also:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427799/15036

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX inherits a set of plain TeX commands that let you change the "class" of each character in math mode.  The various classes determine how the TeX engine inserts white space in a formula.

There are 8 classes:

- 0 = Ordinary `\`
- 1 = Large operator `\sum`
- 2 = Binary operator `+`
- 3 = Relation `=`
- 4 = Opening `(`
- 5 = Closing `)`
- 6 = Punctuation `,`
- 7 = Variable

I think `;` is punctuation by default, but you can make it behave like a binary operator with `\mathbin{;}` or like a relation with `\mathrel{;}`.

The corresponding commands for the first 7 classes are: `\mathord`, `\mathop`, `\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, `\mathopen`, `\mathclose`, and `\mathpunct`.

See the TexBook, p.155 for more.