# Difference between $\star\star$ and $\star\star\star$

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols

[image]

The picture above is generated by `$\star$, $\star\star$ or $\star\star\star$`.

Indeed, this phenomenon was mentioned in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372326/bizarre-spacing-with-4-stars). However they didn't give a solution, and I want to know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bizarre spacing with 4 $\star$s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372326/bizarre-spacing-with-4-stars) (mostly.)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for pointing that out, however they didn't give a solution there. I really like the solution given by M. Logic, which should be the value of keeping this post.

Comment: I wouldn't redefine a standard command, better use a new name or use `{\star}{\star}{\star}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redefine `\star` by `\mathord` which is `\mathbin` instead originally. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537586/140814) for the differences on `\mathord`, `\mathop`, `\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, `\mathopen`, `\mathclose`, and `\mathpunct`. Of course, if you still need the original `\star` to be the binary operator, then you'd better rename the redefined`\star` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{\star}{\mathord}{letters}{"3F}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\star$, $\star\star$ or $\star\star\star$


\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way please give a minimal working sample next time to make people answer your question conveniently.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the reminder!

Comment: But to copy a comment above: "I wouldn't redefine a standard command, better use a new name or use `{\star}{\star}{\star}`".

Comment: I agree with @Teepeemm: this solution is wrong even if the OP is not using `\star` in other situations. It's mostly like `\def\c{\gamma}` that a colleague used to do, but he got a weird error when a paper of his had a Turkish coauthor.

Answer (score 2):

[Bizarre spacing with 4 $\star$s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372326/bizarre-spacing-with-4-stars) explaines why this happens.

I only see a place where this can happen. Quite likely you're tagging equations with , ,  and so on with

```
\tag{$\star$}
\tag{$\star\star$}
\tag{$\star\star\star$}
```

Well there's a much simpler solution for this case, namely using `\textborn` (which is a star).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x=1 \tag{\textborn} \\
y=2 \tag{\textborn\textborn} \\
z=3 \tag{\textborn\textborn\textborn}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

However, since `\textborn` seems out of place there, it's better to define an alias such as `\textstar`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\textstar}{\textborn}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x=1 \tag{\textstar} \\
y=2 \tag{\textstar\textstar} \\
z=3 \tag{\textstar\textstar\textstar}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Oh, well, maybe your font family doesn't fully cover the TS1 encoding. In this case you can take advantage of having defined a suitable command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{somestrangefontpackage}

%\newcommand{\textstar}{\textborn}
% somestrangefontpackage doesn't support \textborn
\newcommand{\textstar}{\mbox{$\star$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x=1 \tag{\textstar} \\
y=2 \tag{\textstar\textstar} \\
z=3 \tag{\textstar\textstar\textstar}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If my guess is incorrect and you're using `\star` as an ordinary math symbol that you happen to get repeated in formulas, then do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pstar}{{\star}} % choose a better name

\begin{document}

$\pstar+\pstar\pstar+\pstar\pstar\pstar=
\pstar\pstar\pstar\pstar\pstar\pstar$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, it would be better to define a command that repeates the given number of stars, wouldn't it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pstar}{{\star}} % choose a better name
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pstars}{m}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \pstar }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\pstars{1}+\pstars{2}+\pstars{3}=\pstars{6}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: So far as I know, we usually have two uses of `\star`:  one is as the difficulty or importance mark which is used in exercise headings or before section titles and in this case we may use 3 or 4 stars at most; another is as a binary operator, for example  `x\star y` in which there should be spaces before and after the star, and `\star` is an abstract binary operator for `\wedge`, `\vee` and so on. For equation tags, we usually use `*`(or `\ast` or `\textasteriskcentered`) instead of `\star`, and `\dagger`, `\ddagger`, `\S`, `\P` and so on in sequel similar to footnote numbers in symbols.