# Correct spacing for Hodge star operator

Tags: math-operators

In my textbook, the Hodge star operator is represented as an asterisk character with the same spacing as in the following image:

[image]

But when I use the `*` character in the obvious way:

```
\[
\ast d \ast \phi = \frac{\partial A}{\partial x}
\]
```

It ends up with spacing like an infix operator:
[image]

How do I get rid of the extraneous space between `*`, `d` and `\phi`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define

```
\newcommand{\hodge}{{\star}}
```

or `*` if you prefer an asterisk. The additional braces will hide the nature of either `\star` or `*` as binary operation symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % not needed here, but...

\newcommand{\hodge}{{\star}}

\begin{document}

\[
\hodge d \hodge \phi = \frac{\partial A}{\partial x}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you replace `\star` with `*` like in

```
\newcommand{\hodge}{{*}}
```

you get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative  is to use a newcommand putting `\mathord\star` or `\mathord\ast` without the curly brackets `{}`, where you can see that you have the same result of @egreg's answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\starr}{\mathord\star}
\newcommand{\astt}{\mathord\ast}
\begin{document}

\[
\starr d \starr \phi = \frac{\partial A}{\partial x}
\]
\[
\astt d \astt\phi = \frac{\partial A}{\partial x}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**PS:** A `\mathord` object is kind of neutral to its left and right neighbours where an unary operator binds stronger to its right neighbour than to its left one (expressed be different spacing and potential break points). [Difference between \mathop and \mathord](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361862/difference-between-mathop-and-mathord)

Comment: You seem to active again, did you finish your project?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Dearest I am taking a break. I have changed pc's, to a more powerful one which I am slowly getting used to. My project is finished; I'm waiting for a publishing house to seriously consider my work and for my professor to decide sooner or later to correct the book. I hope so, but the current strength of my health is not optimal.