# What do empty math character class symbols ("\mathpunct{}") do, and when are they used?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Every once in a while, one will encounter empty math characters with a specific math character class. For example, `amsmath` uses `\mathpunct{}` in its definition of `\colon`:

> ```
> \renewcommand{\colon}{\nobreak\mskip2mu\mathpunct{}\nonscript
>   \mkern-\thinmuskip{:}\mskip6muplus1mu\relax}
> ```

Let's explore the issue with some tests:

[image]

Here is the code that was used to generate this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % to disable a warning generated by \textbackslash

\newcommand{\specialcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
  % for multi-row cells
  % macro adapted from egreg's answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\(abc\) & \verb|\(abc\)| &  \\[\bigskipamount]
\(a\mathpunct{b}c\) & \verb|\(a\mathpunct{b}c\)| & 
  \specialcell{\texttt{\textbackslash mathpunct} will close up to \\ 
               a \texttt{\textbackslash mathord} on the left and \\ 
               create a \texttt{\textbackslash thinmuskip} (\texttt{\textbackslash 3mu}) \\ 
               before a \texttt{\textbackslash mathord} on the right \\[\bigskipamount]} \\ 
    % \verb doesn't work inside of macro arguments, therefore we need \texttt.
    % There ought to be a better way of getting the tablerow spacing I want, one that
      % doesn't require explicit \\[\bigskipamount] (sometimes placed within the
      % \specialcell by necessity).
\(ab\mathpunct{}c\) & \verb|\(ab\mathpunct{}c\)| & 
  empty \texttt{\textbackslash mathpunct} \\[\bigskipamount]
\(ab\mathrel{}c\) & \verb|\(ab\mathrel{}c\)| & 
  \specialcell{empty \texttt{\textbackslash mathrel}: \texttt{\textbackslash thickmuskip} \\ 
  (\texttt{5mu} (\texttt{plus 5mu})) by default \\[\bigskipamount]} \\
\(ab\mathrel{}\mathrel{}c\) & \verb|\(ab\mathrel{}\mathrel{}c\)| & 
  \specialcell{two empty \texttt{\textbackslash mathrel}s are like \\ 
               one empty \texttt{\textbackslash mathrel} \\[\bigskipamount]} \\
\(ab\mathrel{\mathclap{\vert}}c\) & \verb|\(ab\mathrel{\mathclap{\vert}}c\)| &  
  \\%[\bigskipamount]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(The last line shows that `\mathrel{}` is like an infinitesimally thin `\mathrel` with `\thickmuskip` (`\;`) spacing on both sides.)

That two successive empty `\mathrel`s are like a single one is just because there is no spacing between *any* two successive `\mathrel`s. Therefore there is nothing special here.

**When might one use "null characters" with specific math character classes? Is there anything important to know?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well you pretty much said what they do in your question, they make a math atom that has zero width, but which may or may not cause math spacing to be added depending on the class of adjacent atoms.

It crops up from time to time eg here

[Too small space when using \DeclareMathOperator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16649/too-small-space-when-using-declaremathoperator/16699#16699)

And some people use `\mathop{}` in their definitions of the differential "d" letter:

- [What's the proper way to typeset a differential operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14821/14996)  (somewhere on the page)
- [Should I \mathrm the d in my integrals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60545/14996)  (somewhere on the page)

Answer (score 10):

regarding `\colon`, take a look at the comment in `amsmath.pdf` just before code line 272:

> \colon is for a colon in math that resembles a text colon: small space
> on the left, larger space on the right. The : character by itself is
> treated as a \mathrel i.e. large, equal spacing on both sides.

here the `\mathpunct` effectively "disables" the usual `\mathrel` assigned to the character `:` to allow different spacing to apply.

`\mathpunct` is also cited, although it does not appear in the code, with respect to the
definition of `multline`, to avoid an extra `thinmuskip` when punctuation occurs at the end
and equation numbers are set on the right.  (see the comment after line 2311.)