# Spacing around `\circ` with an operator and a letter

Tags: spacing, math-operators

When `\circ` is used with math operators and letters inside `align` environment, the spacing around it is not correct in some cases.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{pr}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \pr \circ f \\
    \pr &\circ f \\
    \\
    f \circ f \\
    f &\circ f \\
    \\
    \pr \circ \pr \\
    \pr &\circ \pr \\
    \\
    f \circ \pr \\
    f &\circ \pr
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

The last six lines of formulas look fine. But for the first two lines, the space between `\circ` and `f` is too small in the first line where `\circ` is *not* behind `&`; while in the second line where `\circ` is behind a `&`, the space is normal, just as the following lines.

Why do the spacings behave this way?

Comment: I think the topic has already been discussed. The `&` can only confuse the matter, but basically, if `\pr` is used in that context, then it's not a math operator.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the link. So it's basically about symbol types. But the problem regarding `align` still confuses me. After further testing I find that,  when I put `\circ f` in odd columns(which are right-aligned), there are no space between `\circ` and `f`, and if in the even columns(which are left-aligned), the space is normal. How does this happen?

Comment: Even numbered columns effectively start with `{}`, which does as an ordinary symbol, but odd numbered columns don't end with `{}`. For instance, in some cases one needs `=` in odd numbered colums in `align`; in this case `={}&` is required.

Comment: As suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16699, I would recommend defining `\newcommand{\pr}{\mathop{\mathrm{pr}}\mathopen{}\mathord{}}`.